# PHP not storing image in directory

Tags: php

Hello experienced Programmers. I currently have in my `../var/www/photos` folder the directory `images/` and the file `Dan.php`.

When I click the upload button when using `Dan.php` in a browser, a success message is displayed. The broken image square shows up though. I can also not open the image in a new tab when right clicking it. The image also does not appear in the `images/` folder. Here is `Dan.php`. I would appreciate your insights and help.

I have also tried doing `chmod -R 777 ../var/www/photos/images`.

```
<!--I want you to use GD Library to Resize the image that is uploaded.
```

If you figure that out soon enough, start researching JS scripts for cropping

images for the profile picture (Ratio should be 1:1)  -->

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo ( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="file">Pictures</label>
            <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" accept="image/*"  multiple="">
            <button type="submit" name="send_album">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <?php
        if(!is_dir('images')) {
            mkdir('images');
        }
        if(isset($_POST['send_album'])) { 
            //for($x = 0; $x < 9; $x++)
            $x = -1;

             foreach ($_FILES["file"]["name"] as $firstNameKey => $arFileDescriptions) {
                $x += 1;
                if ($_FILES["file"]["error"][$x] > 0) {
                    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"][$x] . "<br>";
                } elseif (file_exists("images/". $_FILES["file"]["name"][$x])) {
                    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"][$x] . " already exists. <br />";
                } else {
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$x], "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$x] . '/');

                    echo "Stored in: " . "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$x] ."<br />";
                    echo '<img style="height:150px;" src="' . 'images/'. $_FILES["file"]["name"][$x] . '" /><br />';
                    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$x] . "<br />";
                    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"][$x] . "<br />";
                    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"][$x] / 1024) . " kB<br />";
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes on  your code. Try this.

```
if(isset($_POST['send_album'])) { 
        //for($x = 0; $x < 9; $x++)
        $x = -1;

         foreach ($_FILES["file"]["name"] as $firstNameKey => $arFileDescriptions) {
            $x++;
            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"][$x] > 0) {
                echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"][$x] . "<br>";
            } elseif (file_exists("images/". $_FILES["file"]["name"][$x])) {
                echo $_FILES["file"]["name"][$x] . " already exists. <br />";
            } else {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$x], "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$x]);

                echo "Stored in: " . "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$x] ."<br />";
                echo '<img style="height:150px;" src="' . './images/'. $_FILES["file"]["name"][$x] . '" /><br />';
                echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$x] . "<br />";
                echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"][$x] . "<br />";
                echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"][$x] / 1024) . " kB<br />";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

How you set **save_mode** on your server? This is a common issue. Try upload to directory just 'photos/', not 'photos/images/', works?

If you want to change **save_mode**:

1) Open up php.ini . vi /path to php/php.ini (replace with the path    to your php.ini file)

2) Find the following line: safe_mode

3) Turning safe mode on or off. safe_mode = Off You may active it by    or turn it off by changing it to either On OR Off. safe_mode = On

4) Restart the Apache web server by /etc/init.d/httpd restart or Kill    all exiting httpd connection and run service httpd startssl

Comment: Is this an answer or an question ?

Comment: This is not a proper answer.  Please expand it, explaining what needs to be set to what value, etc.  Explaining the reasons would also be useful.